# shortest path connecting certain nodes in an undirected graph

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph

I have a certain subset of nodes of an undirected and unweighted graph.  I am trying to determine whether there is a path between all of these nodes, and, if there is, what is the shortest path which includes the fewest nodes which are not in the subset of nodes.

I have been trying to think of a way to modify a minimum spanning tree algorithm to accomplish this, but so far I haven't come up with a workable solution.

Is there a good way to do this or is this a description of an already known algorithm?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach that may get you some of the way there:

Use [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) or Dijkstra's to find the distance d(i, j) between node i and node j for every i and j such that node i and node j are in the subset of nodes.

(if d(i,j) = infinity then stop now, there is no solution)

Make a new graph which contains each node from the subset. For each d(i, j), add an edge between node i, node j in the new graph with the weight = d(i, j)

Now use a traveling salesman algorithm on this new graph to find the shortest path to visit all nodes.

This shortest path gives you the length of the path but the path may visit some nodes multiple times. This means we have an upper bound on the number of nodes outside of the subset required.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  would you mind going into a little more detail on how this would work?  In the second step where a new graph is created for each node from the subset what should happen to other nodes which are needed to connect the nodes in the subset, but are not part of the subset?

Comment: I just realized my method gets the length of the path but not what nodes are in it. To clarify, d(i, j) is the number of nodes between nodei and nodej that aren't in the subset. The edge between i,j represents this path (but we don't care about those nodes in the path so represent it as a single edge). You then get the minimum spanning tree. This gives you the length of the shortest path. However it doesn't tell you where the path is. It's now up to you to find a path that maximizes the overlap of nodes outside of the subset..

Comment: The minimum spanning tree will give a path to each of the vertices, not a single path that visits all vertices. I don't think what he is after: (`I am trying to determine whether there is a path between all of these nodes`). This problem is in fact NP-Hard.

Comment: True. I edited my answer. Not sure why I mentioned MST instead of TSP. You can use the MST to approximate an answer for the TSP that is within twice the optimal solution.

Comment: I am still not sure regarding the solution. There are still problems with the method suggested: (1) The path returned might not be *simple* (an outer node will be used twice). (2) If we are looking for non-simple paths - the OP says `"the shortest path which includes the fewest nodes which are not in the subset of nodes"`. This implies a node that is used twice is counted only once.

Comment: lets say the graph has edges (a-b, b-c, b-d). (so nodes a,c,d connect to each other through b) And lets say the subset is (a, c, d). Now the shortest path in the new graph is [a,c,d]. This really might mean [a, b, c, b, d] is the path. The length is 5, but because b was counted twice, we only have 1 node from outside of the subset included. (I think that's what you're saying right?)

Comment: Yes @amit I agree but first we must find the length of the shortest path before we try find a path of that length that has maximized the number of duplicated nodes from outside of the subset

Comment: The 2nd issue (example) is: `V={a,b,c,d,e,f}` where `a,b,c` are marked. `E={(a,d),(d,e),(e,b),(b,f),(f,c),(b,d),(b,e),(e,c)}`. The algorithm will return (`a->d->e->b->f->c`, using 3 not marked vertices, while there is a solution that uses only 2: `a->d->e->b->d->e->c`. The first issue - often we don't allow a path with repeated vertex (classic TSP demand it). No idea if it is the case - but it is an issue.

Comment: He said the graph is undirected, so the shortest path in the new graph here would be [a, b, c], which would give the path [a, d, b, f, c], so we know the shortest path is length 5. Now we need to find a path of length 5 that maximizes the number of duplicates outside of the subset

Comment: perhaps its a mis understanding of "the shortest path which includes the fewest nodes which are not in the subset of nodes" - I believe that means find the shortest path possible. After that, try minimize the number of nodes outside the subset. It may be possible to find a path that requires less nodes outside the subset, but it will be a longer path. e.g. path of length 6 with 3 nodes is better than path of length 7 with 2 nodes used. TSP ensures we do have the shortest path. that's all i'm really saying

Comment: I don't see a reason to continue this discussion - the point is clear, one should understand what he is looking for. If you are trying to minimize the number of nodes not in the subset or is it only a secondary criteria. The comments discussion is informative enough IMO to understand this issue and to conclude what exactly one is after. (if the later, the solution should be a good starter at least, assuming of course you can accept non simple paths)

Comment: thanks. It is an interesting problem. Although NP I would be interested to see what the best approach is to solve.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to determine whether there is a path between all of these
>   nodes

(I understand from this you are looking for a single path that visits all the marked nodes)

Well my friend, this could be a problem - you are describing a variation of the [**Traveling Salesman Problem**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) and the [Hamiltonian Path Problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) (If you are looking for a *simple path*, the [reduction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial-time_reduction) from Hamiltonian Path is straight forward: mark all the nodes).

But I am afraid these problems are [**NP-Hard**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hard).

An NP-Hard problem is a problem that we **do not know of any polynomial time solution** to solve it, and  the general assumption around is - one doesn't exist<sup>1</sup>.

Thus, your best shot is probably going to be some exponential solution. There is `O(n^2 * 2^n)` solution to TSP using dynamic programming, or brute force solution which are `O(n!)`

---

(1) Really not a formal definition, but this is enough information to understand the problem, there is really a lot more into NP-Hard problems.

Comment: I agree with the "mark all nodes". Then to minimize the shortest path if there exists a path of length n-1 it's a Hamiltonian path.

Answer (score 0):

Dijkstra's algorithm or use a breadth first search.

Comment: doesn't solve: `I am trying to determine whether there is a path between all of these nodes`

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm). First, you must assign weights(or distances) to all edges in the graph, every edge that connects two nodes that are not in the subset must be given weight 1. Every edge that connects one or two nodes from the subset must be given infinite weight. Second, you should run Dijkstra's algorithm on the resulted graph.
This algorithm will examine every edge of the graph.

Also, you can use [A* (A-star) algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_star).

Update:
I don't understand this problem at first. As @amit says, this is a NP-hard problem, a combination of HCP and TSP. Maybe some sort of stochastic search algorithm can solve this in polynomial time with high probability.

Comment: Both are shortest path to a single vertex, without constraints on the paths (except being shortest). It doesn't solve `I am trying to determine whether there is a path between all of these nodes`

Answer (score 0):

I created a Graph/Node/Connection classes that not only shows you the shortest path but also can tell you if all nodes are connected:

```
var allNodesAreConnected = StartNode.AllNodes.All(n => n.IsConnectedToStartNode);
```

Or if you want to know what nodes are not connected change it a little bit:

```
var anotConnectedNodes = StartNode.AllNodes.Where(n => !n.IsConnectedToStartNode);
```

More examples and full code in this post:
[Create your own navigation system (with a Graph, Node and Connection class)](https://www.siepman.nl/blog/create-your-own-navigation-system-with-a-graph-node-and-connection-class)

Answer (score 0):

For someone who doesn't really have a background in graph theory, I have tackled this problem and found that in an **unweighted**, undirected graph the easiest method is [Depth First Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). Implementations of algorithms such as Dijkstra's often take a **weighted** solution and input an arbitrary value for the weight.

The solution I found to work I traversed nodes in using **DFS** and log every successful journey, then it's simply a case of  returning the shortest successful journey.

Here's the file that does the heavy lifting:
[Depth First Search Algorithm](https://github.com/steve-westwood/NodePath/blob/master/BL/DepthFirstSearch.cs)